# How to find particular solution of an ODE by fourier series expansion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I encountered the question for the particular solution of, 
$$ k \frac{d^4y}{dx^4} = m x $$
where m and k are real numbers. I would solve this question with basic methods for ODEs but question requires $mx$ to be expressed as a Fourier half sine series (I can do it) and asks to find particular solution of the ODE by using that expression.

I wrote the Fourier half sine expression but how can I find particular solution for that? Variation of parameters method looks too long to be the optimal method for this equation since its 4th order and as far as I know undetermined coefficient method cannot be used since Fourier series expression is not suitable for it.

Comment: When you express $y(x)$ in form of Fourier series, you have Fourier series in the left hand side of equation and in the right hand side of equation (expansion of $mx$). Their coefficients for respective harmonics should match.

Comment: So is it kind of an undetermined coefficient method?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. You just have a countable number of coefficients.